# Angularjs ui-router 404 not evaluating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The scenario is rather simple I have a local site that uses angular. I have my state provider set up us ui router lib.

If I type in http://localhost.com/#/lwejfpwef it will redirect me properly to my other wise clause to the state '/login'.

However I tried typing in http://localhost.com/lwjpoifwef it doesn't fire off any of the events that I have in my module config.
I have tried

- $stateChangeSuccess
- $stateChangeStart
- $stateChangeError
- $httpinterceptors

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. It doesn't seem to hit any of the break points I put in there. Here is a snippet of what I have

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'service', function ($rootScope, $state, service) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, to, params) {
        alert('success');
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, params) {
        alert('start');
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        $state.go('login');
    });

}]);

angular.module('dealer-portal.core').config(CoreConfig);

function CoreConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'wwwroot/app/login/login.html',
            data: {
                displayName: 'Login'
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'wwwroot/app/login/login.html',
            data: {
                displayName: 'Home'
            }
        })
        .state('error', {
            url: '/login'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
}
```

Comment: you can try ro use "otherwise" onto $stateProvider

Comment: I actually also tried that as well and no dice. It just goes straight pass it.

Answer (score 0):

$state.go should have the state name and not the url passed in

```
 $state.go('login');
```

and **NOT**

```
 $state.go('/login');
```

Also, you need to inject `$stateParams` in your run function

Comment: Inject $stateparams where? If you are talking about the stateChangeError it never even hits that event so that probably why I didn't even see that extra / in the .go.

Comment: You need to inject that in your run function angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$state','$stateParams', 'service', function ($rootScope, $state,$stateParams, service) {

Comment: That didn't really do anything. Since I was never using $stateparam, and the param came from the state events not from the run definition.